Measuring type I error rate of non-normal error terms in regression
I've got a simple linear regression model that is trying to test the type I error rate under non-normal error terms. Here is the code for one scenario (Uniform error, variance=100 and b=-a):
b0 <- 30
sigma_sq <- 100
temp <- data$temperature
n <- length(temp)

# scenario 1
rejections <- numeric(1000)
a <- -sqrt(12*sigma_sq)/2 # since (b-a)=sqrt(12*Var(e))
b <- sqrt(12*sigma_sq)/2

for (i in 1:1000) {
  errors <- runif(n, min=a, max=b)
  Y_i <- b0 + errors
  model <- lm(Y_i~temp)
  p_val <- summary(model)$coefficients[2,4] # grab b1
  rejections[i] <- ifelse(p_val < 0.05, 1, 0)
}
type1_percent <- sum(rejections)/1000

The temperature values stay constant. Why am I consistently getting a type I error rate of approximately 5%. Even across other scenarios where the error is gamma distributed or the terms are auto-correlated, I still get 5%. However when I increase n=5000, I get 25% type I error rate for all scenarios.
Is there possibly an error in my code?

It might help to know what the "temperature" data is here :)

Its just Celsius air temperature (with range of 6.818 to 32.225)
